# How to append to text based on condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

How to create a formula in result column based on the values of the previous column 
[image]

if values in any previous columns (from c1 to c5) is greater than zero, I want to add it to the result.

Comment: If you happen to have access to `TEXTJOIN` function it's very simple. Otherwise, with just 5 columns you can write a stacked `IF` condition. If you have way more columns, your best bet is writing an UDF.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have access to `TEXTJOIN` function you can use the following:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A2:E2>0,$A$1:$E$1,""))
```

<sub>**Note 1:** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd></sub>

<sub>**Note 2:** Without access to `TEXTJOIN` this will become a much more painfull process, but for just the 5 columns you can try `=IF(A2>0,A$1&",","")&IF(B2>0,B$1&",","")&IF(C2>0,C$1&",","")&IF(D2>0,D$1&",","")&IF(E2>0,E$1&",","")`, however you'll have to expand to get rid of the trailing comma</sub>

---

If both the above options are not feasible, your best bet will be to write a UDF. For this exercise, you can write a rather simple one:

```
Public Function TextJoin2(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As String

With Application
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = .Evaluate("IF(" & rng1.Address & ">0," & rng2.Address & ","" "")")
    TextJoin2 = Replace(.Trim(Join(arr, " ")), " ", ",")
End With

End Function
```

Call in `F2` like: `=TEXTJOIN2(A2:E2,A$1:E$1)` and drag down.

Comment: @HaroonFuad, has this helped you out? If so consider to upvote/mark as answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=CONCAT(IF(A2:E2>0;$A$1:$E$1&",";""))` as array formula, confirm with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Put this formula in `F2` cell in your example. Expand that formula to whole range
What remains here is to remove comma on the end of result string.

That full formula would be like this

`=LEFT(CONCAT(IF(A2:E2>0;$A$1:$E$1&",";""));LEN(CONCAT(IF(A2:E2>0;$A$1:$E$1&",";"")))-1)`

Comment: If someone has access to `CONCAT` they have access to `TEXTJOIN`. Which makes your second exercise redundant.